# Get data from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a method which takes data from SQLite and displays in a textview but when l press a button show the app crashes. The Code:

```
public void ViewData(){
    btnControler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor data = peopleDB.showData();
            if (data.getCount() == 0) {
                display("","");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer buffer2 = new StringBuffer();
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                display(buffer.append("Name:\t " + data.getString(1) + "\n").toString(),buffer2.append("Email:\t " + data.getString(2) + "\n").toString());

            }
        }
    });
}

public void display(String name, String email){
    TVusername.append(name);
    rphone.append(email);
}
```

The error is appointed to the fifth line `Cursor data = peopleDB.showData();`

```
05-25 23:37:03.439 916-916/info.devexchanges.googlelocation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: info.devexchanges.googlelocation, PID: 916
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor info.devexchanges.googlelocation.DatabaseHelper.showData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at info.devexchanges.googlelocation.LocationActivity$5.onClick(LocationActivity.java:473)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: show the whole stack trace

Comment: Silvia Hisham I have edited my Question with whole stack trace.

Comment: Have you initialized peopleDB?

Comment: This is a null pointer exception. Show the code how you populated the `peopleDB`

Comment: DatabaseHelper peopleDB;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing getting the SQLiteDatabase reference with:

```
DatabaseHelper databasehelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase peopleDB = databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

You can see an example in [this link](https://github.com/Evin1-/w3d1-sqlite-simple/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/w3d1_sqlite_simple/MainActivity.java).

Comment: I dont think so because l have tried both:  
DatabaseHelper peopleDB= new DatabaseHelper(this); and also
DatabaseHelper peopleDB;

Comment: You need to have both lines in your file. Check line 24 and 25 of the following link: https://github.com/Evin1-/w3d1-sqlite-simple/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/w3d1_sqlite_simple/MainActivity.java

Comment: Also, don't forget about the `databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Comment: Thanks Evin1_  solved